# Atheros Wifi works on one desktop computer but not another

Tags: wireless, atheros

My Wifi card worked on my old desktop fine but is not working whe I moved it to my new one.

Here is the output of `sudo lshw -C network`

```
-network UNCLAIMED     
       description: Ethernet controller
       product: Atheros Communications Inc.
       vendor: Atheros Communications Inc.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:04:00.0
       version: 01
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm bus_master cap_list
       configuration: latency=32
       resources: memory:fb200000-fb20ffff
```

and `sudo lspci`

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Sandy Bridge DRAM Controller (rev 09)
00:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sandy Bridge PCI Express Root Port (rev 09)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Cougar Point HECI Controller #1 (rev 04)
00:1a.0 USB Controller: Intel Corporation Cougar Point USB Enhanced Host Controller #2 (rev 05)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Cougar Point High Definition Audio Controller (rev 05)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Cougar Point PCI Express Root Port 1 (rev b5)
00:1c.2 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801 PCI Bridge (rev b5)
00:1c.3 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Cougar Point PCI Express Root Port 4 (rev b5)
00:1c.4 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Cougar Point PCI Express Root Port 5 (rev b5)
00:1d.0 USB Controller: Intel Corporation Cougar Point USB Enhanced Host Controller #1 (rev 05)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Cougar Point LPC Controller (rev 05)
00:1f.2 IDE interface: Intel Corporation Cougar Point 4 port SATA IDE Controller (rev 05)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation Cougar Point SMBus Controller (rev 05)
00:1f.5 IDE interface: Intel Corporation Cougar Point 2 port SATA IDE Controller (rev 05)
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: nVidia Corporation Device 0de1 (rev a1)
01:00.1 Audio device: nVidia Corporation Device 0bea (rev a1)
03:00.0 PCI bridge: Device 1b21:1080 (rev 01)
04:00.0 Ethernet controller: Atheros Communications Inc. Device ff1a (rev 01)
05:00.0 USB Controller: NEC Corporation uPD720200 USB 3.0 Host Controller (rev 03)
06:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168B PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet controller (rev 06)
```

and `sudo iwconfig`

```
lo        no wireless extensions.

eth0      no wireless extensions.
```

and `sudo ifconfig`

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 6c:62:6d:e6:8f:6f  
          inet addr:192.168.0.143  Bcast:192.168.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::6e62:6dff:fee6:8f6f/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:5772951 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:5587811 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:996414964 (996.4 MB)  TX bytes:1604420754 (1.6 GB)
          Interrupt:44 Base address:0x2000 

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:16436  Metric:1
          RX packets:60498 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:60498 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:9892064 (9.8 MB)  TX bytes:9892064 (9.8 MB)
```

I totally have no idea what to do, or even what most of this means, any help at all to get my wifi working again would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Ash

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you using?

Comment: version 10.10 ans as I say it was working on the old desktop, also running 10.10

Comment: Just stop using madwifi.  Ath5k works fine and you can do almost everything through ath5k now.  Try an lsmod if you have issues getting ath5k working to make sure it loads.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look into your logfiles:

```
 dmesg | grep ath
 grep ath /var/log/*.log* | egrep -iv path
```

Maybe issues with an interrupt. I could heal such a thing in the bios, but with intel-IPW2100. Maybe some other idea can be found.

#### update after comment:

On my older laptop, ubuntu 9.04, I get:

```
locate ath_pci
/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-ath_pci.conf
/lib/linux-restricted-modules/2.6.27-14-generic/ath_pci
/lib/linux-restricted-modules/2.6.27-14-generic/ath_pci/ath_pci.mod.o
/lib/linux-restricted-modules/2.6.27-14-generic/ath_pci/if_ath.o
/lib/linux-restricted-modules/2.6.27-14-generic/ath_pci/if_ath_pci.o
/lib/linux-restricted-modules/2.6.28-16-generic/ath_pci
/lib/linux-restricted-modules/2.6.28-16-generic/ath_pci/ath_pci.mod.o
/lib/linux-restricted-modules/2.6.28-16-generic/ath_pci/if_ath.o
/lib/linux-restricted-modules/2.6.28-16-generic/ath_pci/if_ath_pci.o
/lib/modules/2.6.24-24-generic/madwifi/ath_pci.ko
/usr/share/linux-restricted-modules/2.6.27-14-generic/modules.alias.override/ath_pci
/usr/share/linux-restricted-modules/2.6.28-16-generic/modules.alias.override/ath_pci
```

On the newer one (10.04) only line 1, modprobe-blacklist.

But on both a lot of ath5k-files, mainly .ko-related (Kernel object, alias: driver).

Comment: Here is the output:

http://pastebin.com/fSp9FSuE

Answer (score -1):

I believe these cards should work out the box on the newest kernels but unless you want to upgrade your version of Ubuntu, this particular chipset is known to misbehave and forcing it onto the `ath5k` driver should work.

In older versions of Ubuntu, especially where the madwidi driver is involved, the `ath5k` driver ends up blacklisted by other drivers. To fix this, you need to find out where it's blocked. Fire this off into a terminal:

```
grep -R 'ath5k' /etc/modprobe.d/
```

If that comes back with any lines that start with `blacklist`, you need to edit that file and comment the line out. `grep` will output the name of the file so just run `sudo nano the_filename`, stick a `#` in front of the applicable line (control+w in nano to search) and then control+x to save. Reboot and hopefully you'll have a wireless card.

Comment: here is the output: /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-ath_pci.conf:# which ath5k cannot recover. To prevent this condition, stop

Comment: ok, so i did sudo nano and here is what it said:


# For some Atheros 5K RF MACs, the madwifi driver loads buts fails to
# correctly initialize the hardware, leaving it in a state from
# which ath5k cannot recover. To prevent this condition, stop
# madwifi from loading by default. Use Jockey to select one driver
# or the other. (Ubuntu: #315056, #323830)
blacklist ath_pci

ok, so I guess I have to install Jockey and stop madwifi from loading, but what do I load in its place?

Comment: ok, ran jockey and it doesn't say anything about anything other than Nvidea drivers, nothing to do with wifi whatsoever. I tried commenting out the  "blacklist ath_pci" line and rebooted as you suggested and it did nothing, so i uncommented it again